# Regular Expression to match variable number of works with fixed prefix and suffix

Tags: java, regex

Sample input:
Did xxx xxx xxx (could be any number of words) live or die?

For example:

```
 Did   Michael      Jackson  live or     die     ?
```

I want to capture: Michael Jackson, live, die. The sentence can have any number of spaces between words.

How do I do it?

Comment: Umm ... while you can do this sort of thing, I hope that you realize that using regexes to extract information from natural language is going to give you a limited, and fragile solution.  If you want a robust solution you'll need to investigate natural language parsing technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work.  You will need to take the first group, Michael Jackson, and split it by the space character.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^Did (.+)\s+(\w+)\s+or\s+(\w+)$", 
                                  Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | 
                                  Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) 
{
  String []person = regexMatcher.group(0).split(" ");
  String action1 = regexMatcher.group(1);
  String action2 = regexMatcher.group(2);
}
```

Comment: In this example, the text "Michael Jackson" will be split by a single space character.  The end result will be a string array whose elements are "Michael" and "Jackson"

Comment: Yes but your matcher will fail if i have multiple spaces between any word i think, or it'll capture "Michael Jackson live" instead of "Michael Jackson"

Comment: I've adjusted the pattern so that multiple whitespace between words won't keep you from a match.  I don't think it will capture "Michael Jackson live," if only because the pattern explicitly matches the word before the " or " separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
Did\\s+(.+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+or\\s+(\\S+)\\s*\\?
```

or am I missing something?

**EDIT**: changed single backslashes to double backslashes